# Test input Search box with React testing library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a SearchBox component:

```js
    function SearchBox({ search, setSearch }) {
      return (
        <div>
          <div>
            <input onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)} type="text" placeholder="Search..." value={search} />
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

I tried the following:

```js
    describe('Input value', () => {
      it('updates on change', () => {
        const { queryByPlaceholderText } = render(<SearchBox />)
    
        const searchInput = queryByPlaceholderText('Search...')
    
        fireEvent.change(searchInput, { target: { value: 'test' } })
    
        expect(searchInput.value).toBe('test')
      })
    })
```

But then I get an error:

> Error: Uncaught [TypeError: setSearch is not a function]

How and what can I test on this SearchBox component?

Comment: You need to pass in the props the component defines when you render it. And don't test the value of the input, it's not actually that component's job to update it, test the callback was invoked with the right value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue is that `setSearch` props wasn't provided.

`setSearch` can be provided by jest mock function.

```js
const setSearch = jest.fn((value) => {})
const { queryByPlaceholderText } = render(<SearchBox setSearch={setSearch}/>)
```

Full test code snippet:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react'
import SearchBox from './SearchBox'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'

describe('Input value', () => {
    it('updates on change', () => {
      const setSearch = jest.fn((value) => {})
      
      const { queryByPlaceholderText } = render(<SearchBox setSearch={setSearch}/>)
  
      const searchInput = queryByPlaceholderText('Search...')
  
      fireEvent.change(searchInput, { target: { value: 'test' } })
  
      expect(searchInput.value).toBe('test') // OR
      expect(setSearch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test')
    })
  })
```